# NSRegularExpression - match multiple string

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Basically, my string looks like this:

`@"{{attendee.prefix}} {{attendee.firstname}} {{attendee.lastname}}, fwf<br /><span style="font-size:14px;">lalallasgabab {{attendee.weg2g}} {{attendee.5236t2gsg}}  {{attendee.ticket_no}}  agagawfbeagabs</span>"`

I am trying to extract all the string which encapsulated by 2 curly braces:

`[ {{attendee.prefix}}, {{attendee.firstname}}, {{attendee.lastname}}, {{attendee.weg2g}}, {{attendee.5236t2gsg}}, {{attendee.ticket_no}} ]`

I have tried these regex, but it always return 1 match if not the whole string.

`@"(\\{\\{.*\\}\\})"` -> return the whole string

`@"\\{\\{[^}]*+\\}\\}"` -> only match {{attendee.firstname}}

`@"\\b\\{\\{[^}]*+\\}\\}\\b"` -> only match {{attendee.prefix}}

Here is my code:

```
NSString *myString = @"{{attendee.prefix}} {{attendee.firstname}} {{attendee.lastname}}, fwf<br /><span style="font-size:14px;">lalallasgabab {{attendee.weg2g}} {{attendee.5236t2gsg}}  {{attendee.ticket_no}}  agagawfbeagabs</span>"

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{\\{[^}]*+\\}\\}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSRange visibleTextRange = NSMakeRange(0, myString.length);

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:myString options:NSMatchingAnchored range:visibleTextRange];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSLog(@"%@: Match - %@", [self class], [myString substringWithRange:match.range]);
}
```

I have tried using [match rangeAtIndex:index] but still return the same thing, sometime it is out of bound because the match result is only 1.

Appreciate any help here. Thanks.

PS: I am new to Objective-C and RegEx, so pardon this question.

Comment: the 2 answers below (by me and zx81) are acceptable answers, however I would accept zx81 answer to give him credit for allocating time to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all matches like `{{this}}`, use this:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{\\{[^}]*\\}\\}" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
NSUInteger matchCount = [matches count];
if (matchCount) {
    for (NSUInteger matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matchCount; matchIdx++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:matchIdx];
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSString *result = [subject substringWithRange:matchRange];
    }
}
else {  // Nah... No matches.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question, by using different ways of enumerating the result:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{\\{[^}]*+\\}\\}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSString *myString = @"{{attendee.prefix}} {{attendee.firstname}} {{attendee.lastname}}, fwf<br /><span style='font-size:14px;'>lalallasgabab {{attendee.weg2g}} {{attendee.5236t2gsg}}  {{attendee.ticket_no}}  agagawfbeagabs</span>";

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:myString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         NSLog(@"%@: Match - %@", [self class], [self.duplicateBody substringWithRange:result.range]);
                     }];
```

With the code above, I am able to iterate through each of the matched string, which is exactly what I wanted.